# Recovering original UTF8/Kanji/Chinese text from  random/garbage ASCII

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I know this may not be possible but wanna give it a shot anyway.

So I have some data as results of html form submissions. Users originally typed in Kanji in some of the fields. But all I got were random ascii letters like this:

> æŽå°çŽ²

I already fixed the encoding issue (so that new form submissions handle utf8 fine) but would like to see if I can recover the old data (the correct kanji letters) from before the fix.

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:**

Guess a little clarification is needed. As I said, I have **already** fixed the encoding problem for the html form. The actual question is whether or not one can recover the original kanji from the "garbage" data that I already received.

For example, I'm trying to "reverse-engineer" the following

```
ôÃ¼ÒýR
å¼µå¥éºŸ
å†‰æ¦†å¹³
·¨¶vÚ¬
```

Every line is supposed to be someone's name in Kanji or Chinese. I tried all the sensible encodings such as GBK, gb18030, and Big5-HKSCS. No luck so far.

**Last UPDATE:**

Having some luck with BIG5 encoding now. It didn't work for all the garbage data, but it worked for about 2/3 of them.

Comment: Add meta information to your site and forms denoting its encoding as UTF-8, then you should get UTF-8 data on the server. Then you just need to treat it correctly as UTF-8. You're giving way too little detail about what you're doing, this question can't reasonably be answered in its current form.

Comment: Also: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Sorry but fixing the encoding in the html form isn't my problem. Like the title says, I'm interested in recovering original/valid text from garbage letters. The encoding issues for the form had already been taken care of. I'll add more clarification in the question and read your Encoding 101 link.

Comment: Read the article. Good read btw. I'm having a bit of luck now applying the BIG5 encoding to the garbage letters. I guess there's no easy way to go about this other than trying out those sensible encodings one by one. Mind transcribing your comment to an answer? Include your article link in there.

Comment: As I stated in the article, whether something can be "recovered" depends on how it came to be broken in the first place.

Comment: Sure. But you shouldn't get rid of the fact that there may be heuristics that can help reversing the effect. Maybe not fully, but we can always recover information to certain extent when we have something to work with. That's why I asked this question; I wanted to know the possible ways to find lost information due to previous encoding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Character set converter - online tool](http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php)

- Input encoding should be UTF8
- For Output encoding, try out all the sensible encodings for oriental characters.
- Remember to check the 2nd checkbox.

Most if not all of the garbage letters should be recovered.

Comment: good tool! from iso-8859-1 to utf-8 both 'í' and ´Á´ return 'Ã'. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Those letters *aren't* ASCII. No ASCII letters have accents of any kind.

It's unclear how you're reading this data - is it from a file, a database, something else? Anyway, it's possible that it's already *in* UTF-8 - so you should just try to read it using that encoding. You haven't told us what platform you're using, but you should ensure that whatever you *are* using, you get to find out what Unicode characters you've read *by number* - that's a lot more reliable than printing out the values as characters.

Comment: Platform as in server setups? It's a regular LAMP setup. And I'm pretty sure ASCII-II has accented characters. Anyhow, not all of the old data showed up as random letters. I'm beginning to suspect that this has something to do with the way the user inputted their kanji characters. Lastly, yes what you suggested was how I fixed the problem - by explicitly converting utf8 into xml entities using JS.

Comment: Again, the real question is how to recover the old data into regular kanji letters.

Comment: @Dave: ASCII itself doesn't have any accented characters. I don't know what you mean by ASCII-II, but if it's one of the *many* 8-bit encodings called "extended ASCII" then you should be aware that that's *not* ASCII. But you still haven't clarified how you received the data to start with, or how it's stored, or how you're reading it. Is it in a file? Is it in a database? What language is your web app written in? Please give us *much* more context. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions as to what makes a good question.

Answer (score -1):

FYI, the java String class is backed by 2 byte chars, and was designed back when unicode was only 2 bytes.  Thus it doesn't handle the 3 byte Japanese and Chinese characters.  See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/Supplementary/